# Using a regular expression and a while loop to test for a valid number plate

Tags: python

The task states that I have to use a while loop and regular expression to ensure the number plate is in the correct format. The code I have at the moment says "name 'valid' is not defined"

```
import re

def numberPlateTest():
    numberPlate = input("Enter your numberplate:")
    valid = re.match("[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[\S][A-Z]{3}",numberPlate)

numberPlateTest()

while valid:
    print("Try again!")
    numberPlateTest()

print("That is a valid numberplate!")
```

Comment: `valid` is only defined _inside_ the function, did you mean to return and assign it perhaps?

Comment: `valid` is defined only within the scope of `numberPlateTest`. Imagine if you had a program with thousands of functions: how would you manage all those variable names if their scope wasn't limited?

Comment: Thank you, the variable now works, but now the while loop always runs, even when a correct number plate is entered.

Comment: If you never change the value of `valid` when you retry, yes, it will. Btw, are you sure that you want to retry as long as it is valid, and not *until* it is valid?

Answer (score 2):

The function only has one job, validating the number plate. So let it just do that. Input to the function is the number plate and output is a `True` or `False`.
And local variables within a function are not valid outside its scope.
Your code with some refactoring:

```
import re

def is_number_plate_valid(number_plate):
    if re.match("[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[\S][A-Z]{3}",number_plate):
        return True
    return False


# While not valid, keep asking for input
while not is_number_plate_valid(input("Enter your number plate:")):
    print("Try again!")
    

print("That is a valid numberplate!")
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you define valid locally in the function. If you want to call this variable outside of the function, you should return it in some way. Here's an example:

```
def numberPlateTest():
    numberPlate = input("Enter your numberplate:")
    valid = re.match("[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[\S][A-Z]{3}",numberPlate)
    return valid

valid = numberPlateTest()
```